# This query is taking much time how can i optimize this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select a, b, c, d, cast(replace(replace (stuff((
 select ', ' +LTrim(rtrim(e1)) 
 from (
     select e as e1, a, c 
     from table1 
     where a = am.a and c= am.c 
     group by a, c, e) as T 
  for xml path('')), 1,1,'c), '&lt;', '<') '&gt;', >') as varchar) as f 
from table1 am where c is not null
```

Comment: Which kind of database are you using? What is the structure of the tables? How many rows does each table have? Do you have examples of the data contained in the rows? What is the expected output? How much time does the query take now and how fast should it be?

Comment: I am using Microsoft sql server this table is consisting more than 10 lakhs records it is taking 2 hours this time must be reduced

Comment: If I'm correct in assuming a lakh is 100.000 then you're selecting 1.000.000 rows. Try selecting less rows? You could add a where clause. You could select only the first 100 rows.

Comment: But according to the user they need all the rows and time to be reduced.